# Get the user email in Woocommerce "New account" email notification template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

In Woocommerce I am trying to customize the "New account" email notification template changing the texts.

Currently the default template shows the username but intead I want it to show the user email.

I thought I needed to use something like `$user_email` but that shows up blank (or empty).

How to get the user email in Woocommerce "New account" email notification template?

That is the customized template that I got where I need to get the user email:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer new account email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your registered email is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_email ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) && $password_generated ) : ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this template, the `$user_login` is defined and available. What you can do is to use the [WordPress function **`get_user_by()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) with it to get the user email.

So in the template you will have just to replace this line:

```
    <p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your registered email is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>
```

By this instead:

```
<?php $user = get_user_by('login', $user_login );

if( $user && isset($user->user_email) ): ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your registered email is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php else: ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This way you will be sure to don't get any error and you will have the default woocommerce alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The `WC_Email_Customer_New_Account` class object is passed to the template as the `$email` variable. And in the `trigger()` methods the `WP_User` user object is set as a class property `$email->object` [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.0.0-rc.1/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-new-account.php#L100).

Therefore, in the email template you can access the user's email via

`$email->object->user_email`